# Как правильно установить вордпресс тему с демо?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Скачал тему для вордпресс для своего рода деятельности называется Furnicom_lite (беслатная версия поатного шаблона) с сайта templatemonster как бы не старался не получается установить ее правильно (автоматически)

Пробовал установить все плагины вручную, все прекрасно работает конда запущен редактор Elementor, стоит только его закрыть как пол сайта теряет функционал. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

P.S Это моя первая попытка сделать сайт, если что прошу не осуждать если слишком банальный вопрос :)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! Вы же не предоставили токлом никакой информации, а что же собственно не так. Убедитесь что следуете [гайду по установке демо-контента данной темы](https://documentation.zemez.io/wordpress/projects/furnicom_lite/template-installation/index.html#toc-cherry-wizard), убедитесь что Ваше локальное (или нет) окружение соответсвует требованиям к окружению предоставленном в [гайде](https://documentation.zemez.io/wordpress/projects/furnicom_lite/index.html#preparation), ознакомьтесь с [отладкой в WordPress](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Сделал все как сказано в мануале, но идущий в комплекте плагин Jet Elements отказывается работать от слова совсем. На просторах интернета нашел свежую версию этого же плагина, в рамках редактирования плагин работает, стоит применить изменения - белый экран и ничено более с соответствующим письмом на почту об ошибке в текущем плагине

Comment: Jet Elements -- вроде как не бесплатный плагин, а скачать его откуда-то из "просторов интернета", а не с официального сайта -- плохая идея.

Comment: @Simon жалко :( а шаблон то хороший. Ладно спасибо вам